# Shiny Ditto From a regular pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In pokemon x and y, you can find ditto in a certain spot, after snowbell (I think thats what it's called) In this area, if you catch a pokemon, there is a chance that it will change into a ditto. My question is if I catch a regular pokemon (Non Shiny) and it turns out to be a ditto, can it become a shiny and visevera (If I catch a shiny pokemon can it turn out to be a regular ditto)

Comment: This isn't Pokemon Go. If you find a Ditto in the wild, it will be Ditto and not appear as another Pokemon. This makes your question of "if a shiny Pokemon changes into Ditto, can it not longer be shiny" irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

The question's premise is false, Ditto will not appear in the wild transformed as a different Pokémon in X and Y, or in fact in any main series games.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. (Though I was pretty sure once I caught a Zoroark and it became a ditto, but I must have remembered wrong)